# How to use json_exists with CriteriaBuilder in JPA/Hibernate

Tags: hibernate

Am trying to use `json_exists` function for column which stores value in form of List of List - i.e. `[["a", "b"], ["c", "d"]]`.

Using json_exists function in criteriaBuilder to check if that column has given sublist in it. For example it shall return true if given value is- ["a", "b"] which is subset of that list. I tried using below code but getting failed.

```
predicates.add((cb.function("JSON_EXISTS", String.class, new HibernateInlineExpression(cb, "column_name"),
                                    cb.literal()
                                    new HibernateInlineExpression(cb,
                                            "'$.[*]?(@ == "+ sublistValue + ")'")).in(Boolean.TRUE)));
```

Exception:

> org.hibernate.QueryException: unexpected char: '@'

Any pointers to it?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how your model looks like, but you should rather use something like the following:

```java
predicates.add(
    cb.equal(
        cb.function(
            "JSON_EXISTS", 
            Boolean.class, 
            root.get("jsonAttribute"),
            cb.literal("$.[*]?(@ == "+ sublistValue + ")")
        ),
        cb.literal(true)
    )
);
```

Answer (score 0):

> builder.isTrue is required

```
predicate =
    cb.isTrue(
        cb.function(
            "JSON_EXISTS",
            Boolean.class,
            root.get("jsonAttribute"),
            cb.literal("$[*]?(@ == \""+ sublistValue  + "\")")
        )
    );
```